# changing props in react_component when using react_rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, react-rails

I am using this helper to display a `datepicker` component

```
      <%= react_component "MyDatePicker", startDate: '', endDate: ''%>
```

I want to pass javascript values to `startDate` and `endDate` props. Any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by using `Pubsub`. What I did is `publish` the user selected values in the javascript first. Then on react parent component lifecycle method  subscribed to the previously `published` event and use `setState` to change the `state` based on that.

*Now am on mobile but i will publish the code for clarity once i got access to a pc.*

**update**

Using `pubsub` is easy. First we need to `publish` the required from anywhere using javascript

```
dates={some_value:value, another_value: value }
PubSub.publish(OFFLINE_BOOKING_DURATION, dates)
```

Here I just pass a dates object. You can pass anything.
Then in react's `componentDidMount` state I subscribe to this

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    this.token = PubSub.subscribe(OFFLINE_BOOKING_DURATION, this.subscriber)
},
```

Here the first is object we are expecting and the callback

so here is the call back function here you can do anything like ajax call, set state, or anything

```
subscriber: function (msg, data) {
 #this method gets called on receiving data
 #we can access the data we passed like this
data.some_value},
```

And finally unsubscribe when component `unmounts`

```
componentWillUnmount: function () {
        PubSub.unsubscribe(this.token)
    }
```

This is how I implemented it. I no longer have the code but I hope you got the point.

Comment: can you paste the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you're trying to do here exactly but if you just want to get values of your props from the component to your rails controller, do the following.
You can set state of your props in your react component and send an ajax request whenever the user selects a date.

Comment: Am not looking to using it in rails controller but use in react component.  The issue is that  i need to pass the props based on a user selection. As it happens after the component loaded its not working.